# Dynamic key names in object list

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-web-api

I currently have a 'meta' modal box using bootstrap and angularjs, however I want to use this to now save some entered details and post this to the web API sitting behind. This all works fine and happily, however because it is a 'meta' modal, which will be used for all of the different entering methods this means I will need to dynamically create the key of the posted data, i.e.:

```
var dataSender = [{ ID: $scope.iUserItem, ClientName: userItem.Name }];
```

`ClientName` is the item that will need to be dynamically changed each time. Is there a way to pass a variable into this section or will I have to write a different post for each 'meta' data being sent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your object seperately.

```
var myObj = {};
var ClientName = "FirstCape";
myObj[ClientName] = "data" // { "FirstCape" : "data"};
var dataSender = [myObj];
```

Comment: Perfect, I never knew you could add the objects separately, so simple yet brilliantly effective.